# Setting element of PropertyDescriptorCollection in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli, indexer

Being a somewhat simple minded person, I assumed the documentation on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3s6tz2s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to hold true: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3s6tz2s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

...and I actually believed for a while that the indexer property on a `PropertyDescriptorCollection` "Gets or sets the PropertyDescriptor at the specified index number" as stated.

Unfortunately for me it is not so as is quite evident in the property declaration below the introductory sentence. *There is no setter.* The documenters were merely joking in a good-natured fashion.

I have since found a workaround to suit my needs. But what still boggles my mind is that the compiler played along with the joke. Why doesn't the compiler complain when presented with the following?

```
void joke_function(PropertyDescriptorCollection ^collection){
  collection[0] = gcnew FunnyPropertyDescriptor(L"Joking", nullptr);
}
```

On the other hand, the following correctly generates "error C3070: 'Joke2::default': property does not have a 'set' method" as expected.

```
// joke2.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

ref class Joke2 {
  property int default[int] {
    int get(int index){
      return 0;
    }
  }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
  Joke2 ^j = gcnew Joke2();
  j[0] = 10;  // error C3070
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptorCollection%28v=vs.90%29.aspx : "PropertyDescriptorCollection is read-only; it does not implement methods that add or remove properties. You must inherit from this class to implement these methods."

Comment: @Medinoc, How do we know they aren't joking this time?

Comment: In fact, only the writeup of the MSDN page is wrong: The "syntax" part shows it declares only a getter. You can signal the goof-up by using the "rate this topic" link.

Comment: @Medinoc, if that is so, why isn't the compiler flagging the error? That is my original question. Compiler writers should not joke.

Comment: Oh, your're right, I understand now. Indeed, it should be flagging the error. **Edit:** This may be linked to the fact it has explicit interface implementations of indexers (`IList.Item`, `IDictionary.Item`)